# Linux Kernel version4.4 net/ipv4/tcp_cubic.c where is （β,C）?

Tags: c, linux, tcp

TCP CUBIC formula

```
Wcubic=C(t−K)3+Wmax

K=3√(βWmax/C)
```

β is cwnd decrease parameter.
C is cwnd increase parameter.

Does L47 in tcp_cubic.c mean 'β' in the formula above?

```
static int beta __read_mostly = 717;    /* = 717/1024 (BICTCP_BETA_SCALE) */
```

Does L497 in tcp_cubic.c mean 'C' in the formula above?

```
c = bic_scale >> 10
```

Can I set 'β' to 0.2 and 'C' to 0.4 as below:

```
static int beta __read_mostly = 205; /* 205/1024=0.2.. */

static int bic_scale __read_mostly = 410; /* 410/1024=0.4..*/
```

Would this be OK?

I look forward to your reply.

Comment: The comment is telling you the clue. Also, FYI, one question per post. There's four questions asked. The question is not explaining why you want to do it, a bit of background perhaps. Please read the [FAQ] to see how to ask a question.